# ngbDatepicker prevent startDate greater than endDate

Tags: angular, datepicker

I use two ngbDatepicker for startDate and endDate

```
  <input
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="{{ 'Common.SampleDate' | translate }}"
    name="dp1"
    formControlName="startDate"
    [(ngModel)]="model"
    [firstDayOfWeek]="6"
    #d1="ngbDatepicker"
    (click)="d1.toggle()"
    (dateSelect)="onDateSelection($event)"
    ngbDatepicker
  />

  <input
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="{{ 'Common.SampleDate' | translate }}"
    name="dp2"
    formControlName="endDate"
    [(ngModel)]="model"
    [firstDayOfWeek]="6"
    #d2="ngbDatepicker"
    (click)="d2.toggle()"
    (dateSelect)="onDateSelection($event)"
    ngbDatepicker
  />
```

I want to prevent to accept that is startDate is greater that endDate.I tried after() and before() but not working.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit inconvenient and in general, you shouldn't do such things. If you have no other options you can update your second input with a unique name e.g. "dpTwo" and bind it with another property e.g. "modelTwo". But it won't behave as a date range so any range calculations should be handled separately.

Answer (score 0):

You should use momentjs library for calculate the difference between two date/time.

try this snippets:

```
momentA.diff(momentB)
```